# Should I remove meta-robots (index, follow) when I have a robots.txt?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, robots.txt

I'm a bit confused whether I should remove the robots meta tag, if I want search engines to follow my robots.txt rules.

If the robots meta-tag (index, follow) exists on the page, will search engines then ignore my robots.txt file and index the specified disallowed URLs in my robots.txt anyway?

The reason why I'm asking about this, is that search engines (Google mainly) still indexes disallowed pages from my website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a search engine’s bot honors your robots.txt, and you disallow crawling of `/foo`, then the bot will never crawl pages whose URL paths start with `/foo`. Hence the bot will never know that there are `meta`-`robots` elements.

Conversely, this means that if you want to disallow *indexing* a page (by specyfing `meta`-`robots` with `noindex`), you should not disallow *crawling* of this page in your robots.txt. Otherwise the `noindex` is never accessed, and the bot thinks that *crawling* is forbidden, not *indexing*.

Answer (score 0):

With the robots.txt you can tell search engines not to crawl certain pages - but it wouldn't stop them from indexing the pages. If a page which is disallowed in the robots.txt is found by the crawler through an external link it can be indexed. That can be prevented through the meta-tag.
Thus, the robots.txt and the meta-tag do work differently.

https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag?hl=en#combining-crawling-with-indexing--serving-directives

> Robots meta tags and X-Robots-Tag HTTP headers are discovered when a URL is crawled. If a page is disallowed from crawling through the robots.txt file, then any information about indexing or serving directives will not be found and will therefore be ignored. If indexing or serving directives must be followed, the URLs containing those directives cannot be disallowed from crawling.