# How to no index specific URLS?

Tags: php, robots.txt, noindex

I was searching around on how to no index specific URLs but I havent found any specific info on the following.

By adding the below

```php
<?php if(is_single(X)): ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would be able to no index the (X) where X could be the post ID, the post title of “Hello World” for example , or a post slug of “hello-world”.

Would if be possible to specify *all* URLs which start with the same post slug or title for example, as in the example below?

```
www.test.com/REF-123-mytest.html
www.test.com/REF-123-yourtest.html
www.test.com/REF-123-histest.html
```

Could I leave out *all* URLs which start by REF-123 for example?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between crawling and indexing? Robots.txt could help disallowing crawling of your pages, not indexing.

Answer (score 1):

By using `robots.txt`, you can disallow *crawling*.

By using `meta`-`robots` (or the HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag`), you can disallow *indexing*.

If you intend to forbid indexing, [you shouldn’t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25485130/1591669) disallow the URLs in robots.txt, otherwise bots will never know that you don’t want these URLs to be indexed.

In case you want to **disallow crawling**, you could use this robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /REF-123
```

This would apply to all URLs whose paths start with `REF-123` (case-sensitive!).

In case you want to **disallow indexing**, you could add to all these pages this  `meta` element

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

or send the corresponding HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag`:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

Comment: Thank you Unor. I am exclusively trying to no index the URLs but I would like to avoid adding the "noindex" tag one by one. Is there any work around?

Comment: @jiko: No, you have to do this per page/URL, either via HTML (with the `meta` element) or via HTTP (with the HTTP header). Of course you can use a server-side programming language like PHP to include this `meta`/header on certain pages only.

Comment: if i want to disallow www.example.com/test.html i can write Disallow: /test.html  ? also i f i want to disallow www.example.com/category/pen then i can write Disallow: /category/pen ?? Please explain

Comment: @abilasher: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this rule in a robots.txt file:

```
Disallow: www.test.com/REF-123*
```

Comment: This won’t work. 1.) It would block `http://example.com/www.test.com/REF-123*`, not `http://www.test.com/REF-123*`. 2.) Furthermore, the `*` has no special meaning in the original robots.txt specification, so it will be interpreted literally, i.e., only URLs whose paths contain a `*` character at that position will be blocked. 3.) With robots.txt you can disallow crawling, not indexing (however, it’s not yet clear what the OP is really after).