# Is there add "noindex" attribute for some URLs using .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

For example, I would like to block this URL:

```
example.com/?this-url
```

Usually I used robots.txt file:

```
User: *
Disallow: /?$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ask bots not to index your documents, [you have two options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26912013/1591669): either provide an HTML element or send a HTTP header. The latter option can be used within .htaccess:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
```

([`Header` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) from the Apache module [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html))