# Noindex or disallow in robots symfony

Tags: indexing, symfony-1.4, robots.txt

I'm working with Symfony 1.4 and i want deactivate Google's index in my web site, what's the best code i will have to use?

- robots: no-index,nofollow
- robots: disallow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 0):

They do [different](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/72042/17633) things:

- By using a robots.txt, you can disallow *crawling* of your site.
- By using a `meta`-`robots` element, you can disallow *indexing* of your site.

If you want one, you [can’t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25485130/1591669) have the other.

So you have to decide:

- Googlebot should never visit your URLs, but it might index your URLs (learning about them from different sources): use robots.txt.
- Googlebot should never index your URLs, but it might visit them: use `meta`-`robots`.