# Disallow pdf files from indexing (Robots.txt)

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

I have links being indexed that shouldn't. I need to remove them from google. What should I enter to robots.txt
Link example
http://sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/The-Complete-Program-2014.pdf

Comment: What have you tried? Wikipedia has [a decent description of robots.txt with examples](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt).

Answer (score 1):

With robots.txt, you can disallow *crawling*, not *indexing*.

With this robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/2014/02/The-Complete-Program-2014.pdf
```

any URL whose path starts with `/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/The-Complete-Program-2014.pdf` is not allowed to be crawled.

But if a bot finds this URL in some other way (e.g., linked by someone else), they might still *index* it (without ever crawling/visiting it). The same goes for search engines that already indexed it: they might keep it (but will no longer visit it).

To disallow indexing, you could use the HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag` with the `noindex` parameter. In that case, you [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25485130/1591669) block crawling of the file in robots.txt, otherwise bots would never be able to see your headers (and so they would never know that you don’t want this file to get indexed).