# Removing PDF from search results

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, search-engine, robots.txt

Currently there are several PDFs hosted on my site that I want to prevent from showing up in search results.

I have looked into several options such as using `robots.txt`, adding *noindex* through meta tags, or using a `.htaccess` file.

Since the PDFs already show up in the search results, if I use any of these methods, do I still need to manually remove them using Google's webmaster tools?

Would they disappear over time?

If yes, how long?

Comment: For your first question, see [*Disallow pdf files from indexing (Robots.txt)*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32129121/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the PDFs already show up in the search results, if I use any of these methods, do I still need to manually remove them using Google's webmaster tools?

**No**, for future ones from that point onwards provided those rules you set are respected by search engines' crawlers, and **Yes**, to speed up the removal process of the old ones.

> Would they disappear over time?

Removing them using [Google's Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi-ncPwyfTRAhVItBQKHZdqC5AQFggYMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fwebmasters%2Ftools%2Fremovals&usg=AFQjCNGOZzYmuV2SAKcaLlmTglIg9diH2A&bvm=bv.146094739,d.d24), **yes**; they will be removed after some time.

> If yes, how long?

I can't really tell; it may vary depending on prevailing factors and/or conditions surrounding Google interpretation on your intended purpose.